# How do I fix this "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" error?

Tags: unity, android, unityscript

I received my first crash report via the Google Developer Console, yesterday, and I'm completely lost.

This is my error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.JamaludineDolley.NinjaBallDash-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

How do I fix this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error?

Comment: what native android code, services and plugins are you using?

Comment: Only Admob and i have added Google Play service from github to my Unity project. It works fine on all of the other devices so far except the HTC One M8 which gave me the error.